# How to access the state of other computer processes in Java?

Tags: java, google-chrome, taskmanager

I am beginning to write a basic "study-buddy" program as a side project. One important feature I want to implement is that the program can access the state of other programs running to prevent you from accessing them / yell at you. For instance, if you had Chrome open to Facebook, or if you launched a video game. 
First off, is this even possible/reasonable to accomplish in Java? Second, specifically with Chrome, how can I access the programs state from another program that I am writing? More generally, how can I access ALL programs running on the computer and check to see whether anything violates "study-permissible" programs?

Comment: This will be OS-specific.  Can it be done?  Probably.  Can it be done easily?  Probably not.  You are going to have to attach to the OS's running processes to see what's currently running, THEN identify processes, THEN know how to poll specific ones like Browsers to see if they are doing stuff.  In addition, you will need some way to identify games and such, in which new ones are added all the time, so now you need to have a dynamic matching system that gets updated either periodically to keep up or real-time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would put this as a comment, but my reputation point is not enough.
One way is using the commands the operating system provides. You can run a command with

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("<command name>");
```

This will give you the related process and you can get the output of that process just as manually running the process. Then, you can utilize the output.
Basically if the OS provides you that information manually, you should be able to get the information within Java.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Definitely got me started at least.